# Setting the console application text before the cursor

Tags: c#

In Console Applications how do you set the text before the cursor?

For those who may have worked on ArcInfo Workstation a command line application, they had different modules and depending on the module you work in the command line would change to show the different modules. e.g.

```
GRID:\>[Cursor here.]
GRID:\>TIN [Enter Key Press]
TIN:>[Cursor here.]
```

[image: Basic Console App]

The Title property and WriteLine() methods are well known but how do you set the text before the cursor?

Comment: I recently stumbled on [System.CommandLine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/commandline/), haven't tried it out as yet + its only in preview, but it looks interesting and may be up your alley for what you are working on here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Console.WriteLine()` sets your cursor on the next line, while `Console.Write()` - doesn't.

Hope that helps!

Comment: more info: [Console.Write Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.write?view=net-7.0), and (@craig-gers) **Write** is a well known method too.